# Does tiling a Variable tensor in TensorFlow create new variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a (2x1) variable tensor I define as:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))
```

There are therefore 2 variables in the (2x1) vector. I then proceed to tile this tensor like so:

```
W = tf.tile(W,tf.constant([1,3]))
```

We now have a (2x3) tensor. My question is this:

Do we know have 6 unique variables? Or do the 2 unique variables get tiled over the 3 columns?

Comment: You can look at output of `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()` for what the actual graph is. You'll have an op for `variable` and an op for `tile` which are connected to each other, so just a single variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It behaves as you would expect: The original variable is tiled, and there is no variable creation. It is easy to check:

```
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2,1)))
Wt = tf.tile(W, (1,3))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(Wt.eval())
# [[ 0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]]
W[0,0].assign(1).eval()
print(Wt.eval())
# [[ 1.  1.  1.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

`Wt` is not a variable, and cannot be assigned:

```
Wt[0,0].assign(1).eval()
# ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```